# ModX two domains, one site

Tags: php, modx, http-status-code-503

I followed the instructions in ModX: The Official Guide, and created a context for my new site. Then I created the site in Plesk, and put the index.php and core.config.php files from the original site in the httpdocs directory. The site keeps throwing a 503 error, though. Here is the code that is throwing the error:

```
if (!@include_once (MODX_CORE_PATH . "model/modx/modx.class.php")) {
    $errorMessage = 'Site temporarily unavailable';
    @include(MODX_CORE_PATH . 'error/unavailable.include.php');
    header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable');
    echo "<html><title>Error 503: Site temporarily unavailable</title><body><h1>Error 503</h1><p>{$errorMessage}</p></body></html>";
    exit();
}
```

In other words, the new domain isn't able to load the file from the existing one. Is this a CORS issue? I tried adding a header to the PHP file to allow access to the original site, to no avail.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the syntax error (the echo line) a typo here or is that your problem? `$` at the end of the line instead of `";`

Comment: _“Is this a CORS issue?”_ – of course it isn’t … CORS is a _client-side_ matter.

Comment: What value does `MODX_CORE_PATH` have? Does PHP have read access to that folder?

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for setting me straight...The core path is the same on both domains, so I know it's getting to the right folder. The script also opens the file in the existing domain, so I know PHP has access, at least within that domain.

Comment: How about you remove the `@`, so you can see if you get a warning/notice or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MODX_CORE_PATH` in `core.config.php` needs to point to the core folder of your modx installation.